Est-ce qu'il est correct d'écrire "le (les) calcul(s) final(aux) est (sont) égal(aux)"?
Est-ce qu'il est correct d'écrire « le (les) calcul(s) final(aux) est (sont) égal(aux) », mettant ensemble le singulier et le pluriel au lieu d'écrire chaque phrase séparément, pour éviter la répétition ?
Sinon, quelles solutions sont possibles ?

Mais... le singulier ne peut pas convenir, à moins de dire à quoi le calcul final est égal?

Mon but est de savoir comment écrire le singulier et le pluriel sans répéter la phrase.

@YusufJo En quoi cette question diffère-t-elle de la précédente ?

Quelle répétition faut-il éviter ?

Je ne veux pas récrire la phrase deux fois une fois en singulier et une autre fois en pluriel

pas une question de calcul c'est just un exemple

Si tu ne veux pas écrire la phrase deux fois, ne l'écris qu'une fois. Pourquoi serais-tu obligé de l'écrire deux fois ? Si calcul est un exemple, qu'est-ce qui ne l'est pas ? Qu'est-ce qui est imposé dans la phrase et pourquoi ?

car il y a deux cas possibles

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Un calcul est une opération ou un ensemble d'opérations. Je pense que tu parles plutôt du résultat du calcul. On pourra alors écrire:

Les résultats finaux (ou finals) sont égaux.

mais on ne peut pas dire :

Le résultat est égal.

sauf à ajouter par exemple :

Le résultat est égal à celui du premier calcul.

ou aussi :

Le résultat est identique.

Avec identique, on pourra utiliser calcul :

Le calcul est identique.

Dans ce cas, c'est de la méthode qu'il s'agit, pas nécessairement du résultat.

Mais ... tu es donc d'accord avec moi que le singulier pose problème sans préciser à quoi le calcul est égal?

@Frank Oui mais comme je l'ai écrit en introduction, je trouve qu'égal pose un problème avec calcul, que ce soit au singulier ou au pluriel.
